# How to get width and height after JQuery Resizable stops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

Is there any way of getting the size of a div/element after it has been resized with [JQuery UI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/)?

Answer (score 12):

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var width = ui.size.width;
        var height = ui.size.height;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({

    stop: function( event, ui ) {

        height = $("#resizable").height(); 

        width = $("#resizable").width(); 

    } 
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very efficient, why reparse for `#resizable` when you already have `$(this)`?  I'd cache the element first so:  `var self = $(this);` then get the numbers:  `var height = self.height()` and `var width = self.width();`.  **OR** even better using the `ui` variable `ui.size.width;`

Answer (score 1):

you can always use [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) on a jQuery element

Answer (score 0):

In your init object for the resizables, define a hander for the `resizestop` event, where you can then check the size.

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
     // not 100% sure it'll be event.target that you want,
     // inspect in console to double-check
     var width = $(event.target).width();
     var height = $(event.target).height();
     // do stuff with width & height
});
```

Comment: This is what i've got for now:

$(document).ready(function() {
  
        $("ul.list1").sortable();
        $("ul.list1").disableSelection();
        
        $("li").resizable({
            grid: 10,
            resize: function(event, ui) {
                var x = $(event.target).width();
                $(this).text(x);
            }
        });
        
});

but when i resize and "stop" it wont resize twice, if you know what i mean?

Comment: No, don't really see what you mean there. You'll probably need to post some relevant code to jsfiddle to get more in-depth help on this.

Comment: Downvoted because this is what I use and the width is incorrect if borders are used with box-sizing: border-box.

Comment: Soviut, that's good to know, but what's the alternative? Do the ui.size properties (shown in this anser http://stackoverflow.com/a/9119771/97938 ) return values that are corrected for box-sizing?

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler for the 'stop' event.

```
$("#element").resizable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
      var x = $(event.target).width();
      ...
   }
});
```

You can also bind to **resizestop**.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#event-stop